# Check a UITextField for words and spaces in a specified format using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextfield, nspredicate

I am constructing a registration page. The first information socket on the page is a `UITextField` labeled "name".

Within this `UITextField` I want the user to insert their full name in the following syntax: [ first last ]

In order to achieve this result I have reached the conclusion that the user will be required to enter a word followed by a space and then another word.

But I have no idea how to make the program check whether this is the case.

So far I have constructed the following code:

```
// Name syntax (first last).
NSString *nameSyntax = @"[A-Za-z]+[ ]+[A-Za-z]";
NSPredicate *nameTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", nameSyntax];

// If name != [ first last ]
if (!([nameTest evaluateWithObject:self.nameTextField.text] == YES))
{
    [APP_DELEGATE stopActivityIndicator];
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"INVALID NAME SYNTAX" message:@"please enter in format: first last" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [errorAlertView show];
}
```

But the program is rejecting all variants. ie. [ firstlast ] / [ first last ]

Where am I going wrong? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: One red flag I see is your if statement. In Objective-C, `BOOL` is not a true `boolean`, but rather a typedef of `unsigned char *` and `YES` is a macro for `1`. That means when you check against `YES` you're literally checking if some char == 1. In C, any positive integer will evaluate to true in an if statement, which is the idea behind the typedef, so the appropriate way to check a `BOOL` is simply: `if (![nameTest evaluateWithObject:self.nameTextField.text])`. If `evaluateWithObject:` returns any positive integer greater than 1, it will still evaluate to true.

Comment: It's a lot more complicated than you want it to be. Your regex won't handle "Hugh D'Arcy-Jones", for one example. You should search and find a good general regex expression here rather than writing one yourself (and maybe use MATCHES[c] to specify case insensitivity in the NSPredicate.)